# Bool value returns false when the function set it to true in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am facing this problem, created a Audio Player in the document ready and a var for playing as false but every time function seems to be called correctly but not setting that variable to true:
the code is this the function is called from a click listener.

```
var cartSongPlayer = new Audio();
var playingStatus = false;
var playingTrack;

function switchTrack(trackID, trackSource) {
    //logging basic information:
    console.log('Current Track ID ' + trackID)
    console.log('Current Track Source ' + trackSource)

    console.log('Previous Track ID ' + playingTrack)
    console.log('Playing Status ' + playingStatus)

    if (playingStatus) {
        console.log('song is playing')
        if (trackID == playingTrack) {
            playingStatus == false;
            console.log('pausing current song')
            cartSongPlayer.pause();

        } else {
            console.log('moved to new song')
            playingStatus == true;
            playingTrack = trackID
            cartSongPlayer.src = trackSource;
            cartSongPlayer.play();
        }
    //no song is playing
    } else {
        console.log('song is not playing')
        if (trackID == playingTrack) {
            playingStatus == true;
            console.log('resumed song')
            cartSongPlayer.play();

        } else {
            console.log('started new song')
            playingStatus == true;
            playingTrack = trackID
            cartSongPlayer.src = trackSource;
            cartSongPlayer.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mistakingly using the `==` comparison operator, instead of the `=` assignment operator.

Change

`playingStatus == true;`

to

`playingStatus = true;`

Comment: Yes thats the reasons. I was getting tired working all the day and stuck in this situtation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You never change the value of `playingStatus`.

`==` is the equality operator, not the assignment operator (which is `=`).